Is it necessary to include Ziggy with the HandleInertiaRequests?
I'm new to SSR with InertiaJs. I installed Breeze scaffolding with Inertia supporting SSR.
I found below lines in HandleInertiaRequests.php
'ziggy' => fn() => [
    ...(new Ziggy)->toArray(),
    'location' => $request->url(),
],

and below code within the ssr.js
global.route = (name, params, absolute) =>
    route(name, params, absolute, {
        ...page.props.ziggy,
        location: new URL(page.props.ziggy.location),
});

Could someone please explain what is the use of this code? Is it safe to remove it? Because each request includes all the routes we declared in the Laravel.
Thanks
